# Rsync exclude directory using text file not working

Tags: rsync

I have the following `rsync` command to create backup and I want to exclude cache folder from the website:

```
rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude-from='/usr/local/maxicron/rsync/conf/exclude.txt' /home/admin/domains/server.com/public_html /backup/rsync/local
```

To demonstrate, the content of the `exclude.txt` is just one line

```
/home/admin/domains/server.com/public_html/var/cache/*
```

The command works by creating the backup from public_html but I still get the cache folder created in the backup file at `/backup/rsync/local`. The expected result is the folder cache shouldn't have any contents in it.

I read somewhere that the `exclude-from` command would use the absolute path from the source backup. So I also changed this exclude line from

```
/home/admin/domains/server.com/public_html/var/cache/*
```

to this

```
/var/cache/*
```

or

```
var/cache/*
```

or

```
./var/cache/*
```

But none of them are working and I still get the cache folder created. Also there is no error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the absolute path declared in the text file doesn't work. So, I added another option called `--relative` to the rsync like this and I leave the path to be relative path inside that text file:

It works like this:

```
rsync -aAXv --relative --delete --exclude-from='/usr/local/maxicron/rsync/conf/exclude.txt' /home/admin/domains/server.com/public_html /backup/rsync/local
```

Answer (score 2):

According to man [pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) two asterisks (`/var/cache/**`) might help you if the cache folder contains subfolders:

> a `*` matches any path component, but it stops at slashes.

> use `**` to match anything, including slashes.

Comment: I tried both of this `/var/cache/**` and with the full path `/home/admin/domains/server.com/public_html/var/cache/**`, it still creating the cache folder with the contents. When I do `ls /backup/rsync/local/public_html/var/cache/` I still see the cache contents here. Before running the rsync command, I removed the backup folder to test `rm -rf /backup/rsync/local/*`

Comment: Ok. I solved this. I add another option called `--relative` and it solved the issue. Also it doesn't matter whether I use `*` or `**`. Both are working fine.

Comment: I upvoted this answer not because it's working but because you mentioned about that asterisks thing

Comment: and maybe that asterisks thing is useful in another cases but in this case I don't see any effects.